# IOS NSData constructor VS NSMutableData for real time using purpose

Tags: ios, nsdata, nsmutabledata

I have void* buffer...
I need to encapsulate it as fast as possible in a NSData structure (NSData or NSMutableData)

I'm guessing using only one NSMutableData (defined in the class) with

```
- (void)resetBytesInRange:(NSRange)range
- (void)appendBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length
```

or even

```
- (void)replaceBytesInRange:(NSRange)range withBytes:(const void *)bytes
```

will be much faster than using [NSData dataWithData:] every function call...

This is for audio process, so it needs to be the fastest it can be.

Does anyone can confirm that i'll be faster to use NSMutableData instead of NSData constructor ?

EDIT :

the buffer is always the same size, the NSMutableData won't need to re-allocate memory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to replace the contents of an (already initialized) `NSMutableData *data` object with new data from `buffer` of the same length, then the fastest method is probably

```
void *mutableBytes = [data mutableBytes];
memcpy(mutableBytes, buffer, length);
```

because no range check and no (re-)allocation is done. See also the examples in [Working With Mutable Binary Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingMutableData.html).

But of course, as it is often said in this forum, you should profile your app with Instruments to find out where to optimize the program.

Comment: Are you sure, that if the length parameter is the same as the previous data size held in NSMutableData, a (re-)allocation will be done ? Isn't it more "clever" ?

Comment: @TheSquad: I do not understand the question. `[data mutableBytes]` has no length parameter. According to the documentation it "returns a pointer to the object's internal bytes". `memcpy` does not know anything about the `NSData` object. So it is in your responsibility that you do not copy more bytes than the `NSData` object was created for.

Comment: I meant on the method [NSMutableData appendBytes: length:]

Comment: Even with [NSMutableData replaceBytesInRange: withBytes:] since the length is a value of the NSRange, if the length is the same, does NSMutableData does (re-)allocate... This is just out of curiosity, I think I'll use your way, with memcpy... Thanks by the way.

Comment: @TheSquad: I assume that `replaceBytesInRange` will not (re-)allocate if not necessary. With my method you just save the range check. Probably not a big difference.